# Techniques to implement javascript enabled websites that also run without it

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, web-applications, frameworks

I'm looking for design patterns, frameworks or techniques to implement a web page that fulfills these requeriments:

- The web pages are rendered statically at first load, without needing any JavaScript support.
- If enabled, JavaScript should be used to load new portions of the website when the user tries to follow a link, and change the URL accordingly using the HTML5 history api or equivalent.
- If not available, new pages should be loaded statically by following the links.
- I shouldn't write the code twice, obviously. This would lead to inconsistencies.

I've been thinking on this problem for a while but I haven't come with an answer.

Edit: MVC sounds like a good start to solve this problem, but I definitely want to avoid writing the views code twice.

Answer (score 1):

This requires backend support, so the techonology of your backend matters.

That said, this sound an awful lot like the rails library Turbolinks:
https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/

On the front end alone, supporting JS and non-JS is known as *Graceful Degredation* and there are [lots of articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+graceful+degradation&oq=javascript+graceful+degradation&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3.307j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on it all over the web.

Comment: Thanks, the frontend part is covered, but the backend part is what worries me. I'll take a look at Turbolinks.

Comment: Turbolinks seems interesting. I can definitely implement something like this in plain javascript without modifying the server-side code. But I doubt there is too much benefit by doing this. Modern web browsers are probably doing this kind of optimizations already. I'll try a simple implementation and do simple tests and post the results elsewhere. This, however, still don't solve the problem enterely, because all the site is reloaded. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Well it does take server side help... the server has to render the template server side no matter what.  But it also has to be able to decide to render the new content as a fragment for insertion (without the <head> or site layout) or as a a full page, based on how it's being requested.  In order to work without JS, the server _must_ be the canonical source for view templates.  And no, browsers aren't able to optimize this in a way that's as efficient.  It has to parse and execute library source code because the JavaScript context is destroyed when the page unloads.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, I think these links will help:

http://www.implico.pl/lang-en/ajaxgetcontent_dynamic_ajax_website,7.html

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

There is also a github project (browserstate/history.js) to handle this, but I dont post more links, I need reputatión :p